# 'Multiple items found' error when selecting from 'My Recent Items' drop down on standard lookup field

Tags: visualforce, lookup, lookup-filter, summer-18, dependent-lookup

Maybe a Summer '18 Version problem?

I have a dependent lookup field where you must select the value via the lookup window. After you have done this there is a standard lookup field that filters on the previous field. It appears to work normally, but upon saving you get this error 'Multiple items found. Select from drop-down or click icon to refine search.'

In the drop down it appears to let you select any value -- the lookup filter is not being applied.

To resolve this, you need to select the value from the lookup window.

Being able to select a value that is outside of the required lookup filter is a big problem!

I have seen the known issue about actionSupport [https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000sY09AAE], but I am not using this feature.

Lookup Fields:

```
     <!-- dependent lookup field -->
<apex:inputField value="{!line.Warehouse__c}" required="true"/>
     <!-- standard lookup field that is filtered based on above field -->
<apex:inputField value="{!line.Product__c}" required="true"/>
```

Screenshot of error message:

[image: Error Message]

Screenshot showing all the items and their IDs NOT BEING FILTERED in the drop down that appears:

[image: Items in drop down not filtered by lookup filter]

Screenshot showing that in the lookup window the filter works and only one item should be available (the other product is not an exact match):

[image: Items in lookup window filtered by lookup filter]

Any advice is appreciated!!

Comment: Been happing a lot on one of my sandboxes, super annoying. Don't have a fix but I can confirm that its happening. Might take a crack at it if this question doesn't have an answer soon.

Comment: If you select an invalid value (according to the filter) can you still save the record?

Comment: It won't save but it is still confusing/concerning! It gives two errors on trying to save an invalid value:
'Product: Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.'
'There has been an error. Please contact your system administrator. Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.'

Comment: Good to hear. I know if you change some picklist values using javascript you can save invalid selections, which leads to all sorts of problems (like, using an invalid object as the target of a summary field, itll save but then gack when you try to access it).

Comment: @battery.cord any further thoughts on this?

Comment: I dont have the time to dig into it, but I'd like to see more attention to this question & an answer. I've posted a bounty, since you don't have enough rep to do it on your own. Hopefully someone comes in and provides what were looking for.

Comment: What criteria are you using? I have been testing this with two lookups to account (the filter is that the account IDs must match) but have been unable to replicate this, it saves and behaves as it should.

Comment: @CuriousBlueprints If you have an account lookup field and then a contact field filtered on the account id, to reproduce the issue you would need two contacts: one with the same name under the selected account and one under a different account. You also need to select the contact from the standard 'My Recent Items' drop down. (After some additional testing I found you might also need to select via the keyboard -down arrow & tab- as opposed to clicking. Does that help?

Comment: Yikes, 7 days and no answer. I'm having trouble repo-ing it on my sandbox, but I also don't super remember how I was triggering it in the first place. If I have time today Ill dig into this more & try to find a fix.